# Can't Write a Node Structure with Python's ctypes library

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to write a standard node structure using ctypes, but it seems I can't reference the node itself, i.e.:

```
import ctypes

class A_Star_Node(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [("g", ctypes.c_int),
                ("h", ctypes.c_int),
                ("height", ctypes.c_int),
                ("lead_action", ctypes.c_int),
                ("parent", A_Star_Node)]   

    def f(self):
        return self.g + self.h
```

where parent is supposed to reference to the node that came before this node. The error that appears is:

```
NameError: name 'A_Star_Node' is not defined
```

How can I make this work?

Obs.: I want this in Python not in C, so please no suggestions as to write this structure in C and call it inside Python.

Comment: You are way overspecifying the problem.  The code `class A: a = A` by itself won't compile.  Your question is "How do I get to the class-object in class initialization code?"

Comment: @RomanLevin How can I pass that parent POINTER when I'm creating the Structure? I know None corresponds to Null pointer.

Comment: You can't reference the class you are defining inside its own definition, except @classmethods.  The answer in the duplicated question suggests that modifying the class after its definition should work. Alternatively, you could do this with a metaclass.

Comment: Yeah I got that, what I am asking is: when I create the A Star Node I can do it like this: A_Star_Node(parent=None). But when I do have another A Star Node object to pass how can I do it? In C I'd probably do: A_Star_Node(&parent).

Comment: I'm telling you this because I'm getting the error: TypeError: incompatible types, A_Star_Node instance instead of LP_A_Star_Node instance

Comment: Did you want that to be `("parent", POINTER(A_Star_node))`? This will work fine if you delay defining `A_Star_Node._fields_` until after the class is created. Trying to use just `A_Star_Node` makes no sense. It can't contain itself.

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem, I'm not too familiar yet with python even more with ctypes, I just saw that ctypes.POINTER() specifies a type of pointer, and that ctypes.pointer() allocates the pointer itself. That was my doubt, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered:

```
import ctypes

class A_Star_Node(ctypes.Structure):
    @staticmethod
    def getAStarNode():
      return A_Star_Node

    _fields_ = [("g", ctypes.c_int),
                ("h", ctypes.c_int),
                ("height", ctypes.c_int),
                ("lead_action", ctypes.c_int),
                ("parent", A_Star_Node.getAStarNode())]   

    def f(self):
        return self.g + self.h
```

Might work.

Another way would be

```
                ("parent", globals()['A_Star_Node'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work. Printed the same error. The second approach printed KeyError: 'A_Star_Node'.

Comment: By what runtime magic can  `getAStarNode.__globals__` contain a reference to `A_Star_Node` before the class definition is finished executing? Even more amazing is how this magic warps reality to allow a struct to contain *itself*. ;-)

Comment: @eryksun -- many structures contain themselves.  In this case, though, it was an artifact of not re-starting the Python interpreter between tests of different possibilities, so a class contained a reference to an earlier version of a class with the same name.

Comment: A structure can't contain itself. That's nonsensical. It can contain a pointer, of course, as per my comment on the question itself.

Comment: @eryksun -- by that definition, no structure in Python contains _any_ structure of any description.  It only contains base types and pointers to structures.

Comment: It just can't contain itself, because that would require an infinite amount of memory, e.g. you can't define `struct zen {int moo; struct zen;};`.

Comment: That is why you cannot contain a structure within itself *in C*.  In Python, structures are only contained in other structures by means of pointers.  Therefore it is possible to contain a structure within itself, in the only way that the word "contain" makes sense in Python. `a.moi = a` is perfectly sensible in Python.

Comment: You cannot do this in `_fields_` for the same reason you can't do it in C. OTOH, as an regular attribute in the class `__dict__` it's just a reference, which is just a `PyObject *` pointer under the hood in CPython.